# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$wire') at Livewire.value (VM951 livewire.js:13:145634)

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have error with google map when it put Marker it get this error
I do not know what the error is when I click on save it outputs that the data is  field is required. in the map it selects the place but when I click on the place this error comes out at the bottom

```
VM951 livewire.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$wire')
    at Livewire.value (VM951 livewire.js:13:145634)
    at placeMarkerAndPanTo (make:2811:27)
    at make:2792:11
    at geocoder.js:6:1385
    at geocoder.js:3:420
    at bza (geocoder.js:2:218)
    at gia.e [as m] (geocoder.js:3:339)
    at Object.c [as _yj5gms] (common.js:123:253)
    at GeocodeService.Search?5m2&1d24.745676471010597&2d46.7278229712639&9sen-US&callback=_xdc_._yj5gms&key=AIzaSyDy4tKkS30XU9DJsUA5cqLzg-jtynKS18s&token=45746:1:28
```

I do not know what the error is when I click on save it outputs that the data is  field is required. in the map it selects the place but when I click on the place this error comes out at

this is my code

```
@section('scripts')

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{env("GOOGLE_KEY")}}&libraries=places&v=weekly"> </script>


<script src="{{ asset('dashboard/assets/js/pages/crud/forms/widgets/select2.js') }}"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#kt_select2_3').select2({
      placeholder: '',
    }).on('change', function() {
      @this.properties = $(this).val();
    });
  });

  function mapLocation() {
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;

    var lat, lng;
    var markers = [];
    var gmarkers = [];

    function initialize() {
      directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      var riyad = new google.maps.LatLng(24.729518, 46.723341);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: riyad,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);


      map.addListener('click', function(e) {

        var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({
          'latLng': e.latLng
        }, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            //alert(results[1].formatted_address);
            if (results[1]) {

              //results = results[1];
              //var result12 = results[1].formatted_address;
              // //document.getElementById("address_pickUp").innerHTML = results[1].formatted_address;
              // // alert(document.getElementById("address_pickUp").innerHTML.length)
              // if(document.getElementById("address_pickUp").innerHTML.length == 0){
              //   document.getElementById("address_pickUp").innerHTML = results[1].formatted_address;
              // }else{
              //   document.getElementById("address_dropOff").innerHTML = results[1].formatted_address;
              // }
              //@this.address = results[1].formatted_address;

              // alert("Location: " + results[1].formatted_address + "\r\nLatitude: " + e.latLng.lat() + "\r\nLongitude: " + e.latLng.lng());
              //alert(result12);

            }
          }


          placeMarkerAndPanTo(e.latLng, map, results[1].formatted_address);
        });
      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        // position: markers[0],
        position: markers,
        map: map
      });

      function placeMarkerAndPanTo(latLng, map, results) {

        if (document.getElementById("pickup_lat").value.length == 0) {
          document.getElementById("pickup_lat").value = latLng.lat();
          document.getElementById("pickup_lng").value = latLng.lng();
          document.getElementById("address_pickUp").value = results;

          marker.setPosition(latLng);
          map.panTo(latLng);
          @this.pickup_lat = latLng.lat();
          @this.pickup_lng = latLng.lng();

        } else {
          document.getElementById("dropoff_lat").value = latLng.lat();
          document.getElementById("dropoff_lng").value = latLng.lng();
          document.getElementById("address_dropOff").value = results;
          marker.setPosition(latLng);
          map.panTo(latLng);
          @this.dropoff_lat = latLng.lat();
          @this.dropoff_lng = latLng.lng();

        }
      }
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('routebtn'), 'click', calcRoute);

      // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
      var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
      var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

      // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
      map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
        searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
      });

      var markers = [];
      // [START region_getplaces]
      // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
      // more details for that place.
      searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
        if (places.length == 0) {
          return;
        }
        // Clear out the old markers.
        markers.forEach(function(marker) {
          marker.setMap(null);
        });
        markers = [];

        // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        places.forEach(function(place) {
          var icon = {
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
          };

          console.log("latitude: " + place.geometry.location.lat() + ", longitude: " + place.geometry.location.lng());

          /*if (document.getElementById("pickup_lat").value.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById("pickup_lat").value = place.geometry.location.lat();
            document.getElementById("pickup_lng").value = place.geometry.location.lng();
            // marker.setPosition(latLng);
            // map.panTo(latLng);
            //@this.pickup_lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
            //@this.pickup_lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
          } else {
            document.getElementById("dropoff_lat").value = place.geometry.location.lat();
            document.getElementById("dropoff_lng").value = place.geometry.location.lng();
          }*/
          // Create a marker for each place.
          markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location

          }));

          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            // Only geocodes have viewport.
            bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
          }
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      });
    }
```

@endsection

**make-trip.blade.php**

```
<div class="col-lg-12" wire:ignore>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <x-input type="text" field="map" style="margin: 10px; z-index: 0; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; left: 0px; top: 0px;width:350px" placeholder="Search Box" id="pac-input"></x-input>
  </div>
```

```
I do no now what is the error
```